# Modify context after using form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I have a view that shows a list of objects that have specific tag.

```
class AllView(ListView):

    context_object_name = 'facts'
    template_name = 'facts_blog/all_facts.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(AllView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if 'TagForm' not in context:
            context['TagForm'] = TagForm()
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        form = TagForm(self.request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            context = RequestContext(self.request)
            return self.send_results(form.cleaned_data['tag'])
        else:
            return Fact.objects.all()

    def send_results(self, tag):
        return Fact.objects.filter(tags__slug=tag)
```

I want to return form.cleaned_data['tag'] to template, but i have already used get_context_data... What should I do to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding what you're saying, you want to include the "tag" in your context dict while the ListView queryset will return the "Fact" instances associated with the tag. Correct?

If you look at Django's `BaseListView` the `get` method will call `get_queryset` first, then right before it calls `render_to_response` it will call your `get_context_data` method:

```
class BaseListView(MultipleObjectMixin, View):
    """
    A base view for displaying a list of objects.
    """
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
        allow_empty = self.get_allow_empty()

        # [snip]
        # some code not related to this omitted
        # [snip]

        context = self.get_context_data()
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

What you can do is set an attribute (`self.object`) in your `get_queryset` method to store the "tag" from your validated form, then retrieve it in your `get_context_data` method so you can stuff it in the context dict:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    form = TagForm(self.request.GET)
    if form.is_valid():
        context = RequestContext(self.request)
        # set self.object to the "tag"
        self.object = form.cleaned_data['tag']
        return self.send_results(self.object)
    else:
        # set self.object to None since the form is not validated
        self.object = None
        return Fact.objects.all()

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(AllView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    if 'TagForm' not in context:
        context['TagForm'] = TagForm()
    # put self.object in the context dict
    context['tag'] = self.object
    return context
```

Your template will then have a var called `tag` with either the "tag" value or `None`.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what i wanted and your solution have done this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the form's action returns to the AllView view via GET request, you can modify the `get_context_data` in this way:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(AllView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    if 'TagForm' not in context:
        context['TagForm'] = TagForm()

    tag_form = TagForm(self.request.GET)
    if tag_form.is_valid():
        context['tag'] = tag_form.cleaned_data.get('tag')

    return context
```

Hope it does the trick.